# I add values into a C array in one function, array is still empty in later function, what gives?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, dereference

The pointer is declared

```
int *v;
```

And the two functions are called.

```
createMemObjects(M, N, v, context);
transferToDevice(M, v, commands);
```

So in my first function which I pass int *pv into, I fill the array:

```
pv = malloc(sizeof(int) * M); 
memset(pv, 0, sizeof(int)*M);

for (int i = 0; i<M; i++) {
        pv[i] = N; //Initialise every element of vector with N.
        printf("Element %d: %d\n", i, pv[i]);
    }
```

The print shows that pv has been filled with N=2.

In a later function which *pv as an argument again, I use a similar print loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<M; i++) {
        printf("Element %d: %d\n", i, pv[i]);
    }
```

And instead of 2s, it shows all elements to be back to 0. What am I doing wrong? Pretty sure I've been using pointers correctly, but is there something I've missed?

Comment: Can you show some more code please?  The problem is likely to be in the function that calls the two functions you've included snippets from.

Comment: Does something funky happen in the code that calls your two function and passes them the `pv` argyments?

Comment: We can't help you without the actual code.

Comment: Is `v` assigned to valid memory before use? I am guessing that `createMemObjects()` performs a `v = malloc(sizeof(int) * m);` in which case it won't be visible to the caller.

Comment: Err... might it be you are programming with CUDA or OpenCL there?

Comment: Yeah but wrapping it in a C program

Comment: So is `v`/`pv` actually residing in host or device memory? Without posting more code all we can do is guessing here...

Comment: There you go. As @hmjd pointed out: you need to pass a pointer to the pointer `*v` into `createMemObjects()`. Otherwise you are just setting a local variable inside `createMemObjects()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented, you need to pass the *address* of the pointer `v` as C passes arguments by value, including pointers. As the code stands, a *copy* of `v` is being assigned within `createMemObjects()` so the change is not visible to the caller:

```
/* Invoke as */
createMemObjects(M, N, &v, context);
```

Change argument type of `v` to `int**` and within `createMemObjects()`:

```
*pv = malloc(sizeof(int) * M);
```

The `memset()` immediately after `malloc()` is superfluous as the `for` is initalizing each `int` in `pv`.

Comment: Still not quite working, I'm getting a bad access signal after that parameter and argument change?

Comment: @Chucky, see http://ideone.com/nWCnad for example. When assigning in the `for` loop within the `createMemObjects()` function use `(*a_pv)[i] = 2;`.

Comment: Oh of course, because you need to dereference first and then apply the index. Thanks for the help!